# App container not connecting properly to postgres database in deployment

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js, nestjs

TLDR: NestJs server with PostgreSQL database and sequelize-typescript ORM working in development (started locally via npm and postgres database running on mac) but not when builded and deployed containerized with docker-compose.

I've pinned the problem down up to this point in my `database.provider.ts` where the connection to the database via sequelize-typescript is made:

```
export const databaseProviders = [
{
    provide: 'SEQUELIZE',
    useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const sequelize = new Sequelize(configService.sequelizeOrmConfig);
        sequelize.addModels([
            Model1,
            Model2,
            Model3,
        ]);
        await sequelize.sync();
        return sequelize;
    },
    inject: [ConfigService],
},];
```

The application container is starting up to this point: `await sequelize.sync();`
From there the app does not start further, so i guess something is blocking the connection to the database. When i comment this part out, the app is starting (but of course without database-connection). When i run it locally in development it works too.

Maybe my docker-compose.yml is relevant too:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  testname_app:
    container_name: testname_app
    image: registry.acme.com/test/test 
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    networks:
      - testname-network
    restart: unless-stopped

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - testname-network
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  testname-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by switching from `FROM node:latest` to `FROM node:lts` in my Dockerfile. Memo to myself: Never pulling from latest again.